# SystemToken/PushToken null when setting MobileMarketingSdk on Android

Tags: android, mobilepush-android

I've finished setting up the MobileMarketingSdk on Android to send PushNotifications, and after a few tries, I'm still not able to have the contact properly added to the contacts, while debugging I could notice that both SystemToken and PushToken are null, but I can retrieve the FirebaseToken with

`val token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token`

I've managed to fire the push notification with the script on the 5. of this link: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html

using the token from firebase, but apparently something is wrong with the setup with salesforce, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

I also used the "Legacy server key", as the docs refer. Here is my sdkStatus, if it helps: https://gist.github.com/jrafaelm/0f924ecd67f5de2d39d96fd172d38fb9

Update:
using this code to log everything from MC:

`MarketingCloudSdk.setLogListener(MCLogListener.AndroidLogListener())`

here is the log of the exception:
https://gist.github.com/jrafaelm/ad8027acc207d6344a414594ba77d070

Comment: If you enable SDK logging (http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/loginterface.html) and try a fresh install you should see "Sender Id has changed.  Refresh system token." in the verbose channel during the SDK's initialization. A few moments later you should see "handlerTokenRequest" in the verbose channel.  After that you will either see an exception in the error channel with a message of "Failed to complete token refresh" or a new registration will be sent to the MT.  Can you verify what you're seeing in the logs?

Comment: thanks Seth, I've setup the logs now, and yes I'm facing a Failed to complete token refresh

Sdk Version: 5.3.2 Google Play Services Version: 11400000

Comment: There should be an exception that was logged along with that message.  Did it help you to resolve the issue?  If not, can you update the queston with the stacktrace?

Comment: Seth, I attached the log, I didn't find anything really useful on it, do anything give you any clue of the issue?

Comment: There is an exception that will be logged that is missing from the logs you provided.  If you use the MCLogListener.AndroidLogListener as your log listener for the SDK then you will see it in the logcat.

Comment: Now we're talking! The exception is java.io.IOException: INVALID_SENDER, I'm looking into it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting
`MarketingCloudSdk.setLogListener(MCLogListener.AndroidLogListener())`

I was able to see the exception, and found out that I was setting the senderId wrong within the initialization method. I was passing the legacy server key. Sender ID is located below the server keys at firebase console!